# How to create a symlink from a given installation of postgis to the postgresql@13 version in macos?

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgis, postgresql-13, macos-sonoma

I have installed `postgresql@13` and postgis on macos Sonoma 14.1.1 using `brew install...`. The postgis version installed by default is `3.3.4_1` and it works with postgresql@14, thus it installed it too.

The problem I have is that when running `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` on `psql -U postgres` having started postgresql@13, I got:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/share/postgresql@13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

I have read that I have to create a symlink from given installation of postgis to the desired postgresql@13. But I don't know how to do it.

Can someone provide some help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why oh why do you want to do that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, cus I'm having this error: `ERROR:  could not open extension control file"/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/share/postgresql@13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`. If there is another way to solve it, I would like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load a library built for one major PostgreSQL version with a different PostgreSQL version.  There is a special protection agaist that that will result in an error like

```
ERROR:  incompatible library "postgis.so": version mismatch
DETAIL:  Server is version 13, library is version 14.
```

So don't try messing up the installation with symbolic links.  If you cannot find fitting binary packages, you can build PostGIS from source.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I build PostGIS from source?

Comment: Build instructions are [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/postgis_installation.html#PGInstall).